# Appstoreconnect error, unable to delete or remove previous build

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

We built an app through flutter, but can't make changes on Appstoreconnect.

They are requesting for new binary for review but all the options are blocked as below screenshot.

We would greatly appreciate any kind of comment, this problem has been ongoing for 3wks and it is killing us..

[Appstoreconnect error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j03uZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your app is "Ready for review", so you cannot change the build.  You need to change the state to "Prepare for submission".

1. Go to "App Review" - The last item on the left under "General"
2. Click "View" on the far right in the "Ready for Review" table
3. Hover over the app icon a red "-" will appear - Click this.
4. Confirm you want to remove from submission.
5. You can now remove your build and add a new one.

Yes, this is confusing and unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Dear, Paul Thank you for your reply! The red "-" doesn't appear and we tried firefox, chrome and safari. I think it it appstoreconnect rendering issue or error. It has been ongoing for 3wks and even after they fix things and give feedback, similar problem continues..

Comment: Did you successfully change your app status from "ready for review" to "Prepare for submission"?  I used exactly these steps when preparing this answer and it worked for me.

Comment: There should be an action button or blue grid pop-up on the section above, but it doesn't show on the screen.

Comment: You won't see a delete button until the state of your app is "prepare for submission".  In your screen shot it is "ready for review".  Have you followed my directions to change it to "prepare for submission"?